# Copy <td> element content in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to write JS code that can copy the content of a `td` and, at the same time, shows some kind of notification to let the user know that something has been copied to the clipboard.
I tried the following code and the copying to clipboard works fine, but the notification never worked.
What should I do?

PHP and HTML:

```
echo "<td onClick='copy(this),selectThis(this)'> " . $row['email'] . "</td>";
```

JS:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function copy(that){
        var inp =document.createElement('input');
        document.body.appendChild(inp)
        inp.value =that.textContent
        inp.select();
        document.execCommand('copy',false);
        inp.remove();
    }
    function selectThis(element) {
        document.createElement("input")).style.backgroundColor = "red";
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I copy to the clipboard in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/400212/how-do-i-copy-to-the-clipboard-in-javascript)

Comment: Thanks for your comment sir, but I don't want the alert box, very ugly and wasting time.
i need something like message fade in and out, or something at the right bottom of the cell

Comment: *i need something like message fade in and out, or something at the right bottom of the cell*
 I think you need https://codeseven.github.io/toastr/demo.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
'use strict';
function copy(that){
 // ...
 notify(that.textContent);
}

function notify(content) {
  let notification = document.createElement('span');
  notification.classList.add('notification');
  notification.textContent = `"${content}" copied`;
  document.body.prepend(notification);
  setTimeout(() => notification.remove(), 4000);
}
```

```css
.notification {
  border: solid 1px green;
  padding: 5px;
  animation-name: fade;
  animation-duration: 4s;
  animation-iteration-count: 2;
  animation-direction: alternate;
 }
 
@keyframes fade {
  from { opacity:0; }
  to { opacity:1; }
}
```

```html
<p onclick="copy(this)" id="element" >Click here to copy this text (figuratively).</p>
```